# Unable to return result of connection.query to other function in nodejs

Tags: mysql, node.js, aws-lambda

I am trying to insert data into the mysql table through lambda.

insert.js:

```
var connection = require('../common/connection');

exports.insertData = async (request, context, callback) => {
    var query = "INSERT INTO " + request.tableName + "(" + request.columnsString + ") VALUES ( " + request.valuesString + ")";
    await connection.connection().query(query, function (error, results) {
        connection.connection().destroy();
            if (error) {
                callback(error,null);
            } else {
                console.log(results.insertId);
                callback(null, results.insertId);
            }
    });
};
```

callinsert.js:

```
exports.insertCall = async (request, context, callback) => {
        var abc = await insert.insertData(request, context, callback);
        console.log("abv:", abc);
        return abc;
};
```

This code returns undefined.

And results of console.log are like:

first time when I test the code it gives me right result with return value for  id as 1. But second time it gives me 1 again. when i run it next time it gives me the id of previous row(i.e. if 3rd is inserted it returns 2, if 4th row is inserted it returns values as 3 and so on).And sometimes it returns same value of previous id.I am not getting proper results.please help me to find what i am doing wrong here.

Result of console.log on 1st test:

```
INFO    abv: undefined
INFO    Connected to database.
INFO    1
```

Comment: This code cannot work properly.  You cannot mix plain callbacks (like your `.query()` callback) with promises and `await`.  It will not work.  The `await` does not know how to `await` a plain callback result.  Instead, if you want to use `await`, then convert all asynchronous operations to promises and construct your logic and flow entirely with promises.  If you don't know how to convert a plain callback to a promise, look at `util.promisify()` in node.js and search for the term "promisify".

Comment: Thanks @jfriend00. Its working with util.promisify